# c++ store data in middle of an aligned array

Tags: c++, alignment, intel

```
#include<cstdint>
#include<iostream>
#include<immintrin.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    alignas(32) int32_t a[32];
    __m256i t256(_mm256_setzero_si256());
    _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(a),t256);
    cout<<"pass"<<endl;
    _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(a+8),t256);
    cout<<"pass"<<endl;
    _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(a+4),t256);
    cout<<"pass"<<endl;
}
```

I get three "pass" while running this program in windows (compiling by vs2017 15.6.6 and CPU is i7-6700HQ).
However, I get `Segmentation fault` while running the third statement in arch linux (compiling by g++ 7.3.1 & clang 6.0.0 and CPU is i7-7820x).
The options I use is `-std=c++17 -march=native`.
In my opinion, I can store in everywhere inside `a`, because `a` is align on a 32-byte boundary, and every elements is a 32 bit integer.

But what do I get `Segmentation fault`?
[Intel _mm256_store_si256](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_store_si256)

Comment: Does `__m256i` need to be aligned to a 32 byte (256 bit) boundary? `a+4` isn't on a 32 byte boundary.

Comment: @kevin Each elements is 32 bit integer, so `a+1` `a+2` `a+3` ... should also align on 32-byte boundary, isn't?

Comment: No, `a+1` is on a 32 bit (4 byte) boundary.

Comment: @Kevin I got it, it is 32-`byte` boundary instead of 32-`bit` boundary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__m256i` needs to be aligned to a 32 byte (256 bit) boundary. Since the array `a` is aligned to a 32 byte boundary via `alignas(32)`, the addresses `a` and `a+8` (equivalent address to `(char*)a + 8*sizeof(int32_t)`) are also aligned to 32 byte boundaries.

However `a+4` is not. Its address will be between two 32 byte boundaries. Because of this your third statement has undefined behavior and may do different things on different architectures.

Comment: On different *compilers*, you mean.  Intel intrinsics can only compile for x86.  But yes, some compilers use `vmovdqu` (unaligned store) even when the source uses `store` instead of `storeu`, to be more "forgiving".  (Or to disable your ability to build a version that uses HW alignment checking to detect potential performance issues.)